# Processing language - writing a basic program of data

Tags: processing

So I have just started studying processing at university, but unfortunately missed the firth few lectures, so with the text books at hand, I am attempting to learn this my self, could someone let me know if im right or wrong with this?  You would be saving my life. kinda..  thanks :D

This is the question:

> Write a program which declares and initialises the following variables
>   with their values. Add comments to your program to separate the
>   different subsections. i. noOfstudents =50 ii.  examMark = -50
>   iii.  priceOfShoes = 59.99 iv.  income = 10,750.99             v.
>   greetingMessage='hello there'   vi. alphabet = 'A'
>
> vii  lossOfIncome = -20.30
>    viii    sum=0.0000000000076

and this is the code I have typed up for the question;

```
void setup() {
int noOfStudents;
noOfStudents = 50; //Number of Students
float examMark;
examMark = -50; // Exam Mark
float shoePrice;
shoePrice = 59.99; // The price of the shoes
double income;
income = 10750.99; // The income
print ("hello world"); //displays hello world
char message;
message = 'A'; //displays the character A

float lossOfIncome = -20.30;
double lossOfIncome2 = 0.0000000000076; //The loss of income

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could declare and init your variables on one line, ie `int noOfStudents = 50;`. Also, you are using the `print()` method. It is more likely you would want to use the `String` variable type.

You might also want to take a look at Ch. 4 of Daniel Shiffman's, Learning Processing book, or at least the examples for ch. 4 online.

http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/

Comment: Great thanks loads! I have Daniel Shiffmans book on loan from uni so will check out chap4. Thanks again!